# Consumir Web Service con SOAP WSDL y C#

Tags: c#, web, soap, wsdl

Estoy intentando crear un cliente en **`C#`** con una aplicación de consola para consumir un servicio web externo mediante `wsdl` y `soap` (sin cabecera), además con usuario y contraseña (**autenticación básica**), pero no lo consigo.

Tengo el WSDL (http://apps.ejemplo.com/serviciopedidos/servicio.php?wsdl) y las claves.

En cierto sitio del wsdl viene esta información, por si es útil:
`<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>`

De momento, he intentado varias veces agregar una referencia web con `Visual Studio 2017`

**(Agregar-> Referencia de Servicio-> Avanzadas-> Agregar Referencia
web...).**

Mi código es el que sigue:

```
com.ejemplo.apps.pedidos p = new com.ejemplo.apps.pedidos();
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(2019, 05, 05);

 WSClient.com.ejemplo.apps.pedidos ws = new 
 WSClient.com.ejemplo.apps.pedidos();
 ws.PreAuthenticate = true;
 ws.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "clave");

 var a = ws.leerPedidosFecha(dt);
```

Sin embargo, al `leerPedidosFecha` me devuelve

> "El Cliente encontró el tipo de contenido de respuesta 'txt/xml;
>   charset=UTF-8', pero se esperaba 'txt/xml'.

Es la primera vez que hago esto y no sé qué me falta.
Gracias.

Comment: En vez de agregar una referencia web, porque no pruebas agregando una referencia de servicio.

Comment: Hola @alfonso hay algún mensaje de error más extenso? Entiendo que puede haber más información en el `InnerException` de la misma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para arreglar el error del tipo de contenido recibido, debes hacer un override del sevicio, algo tal que asi:

Creas una clase, la que yo he llamado overGetRequest

```
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public class overGetRequest : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{

    //Para usar la sobreescritura, editar Reference.cs y cambiar el 
    //System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol de la declaracion del servicio
    //por overGetRequest

    protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        //Esto esta comentado por si no necesitas autenticar
        //byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(Properties.Settings.Default.usuarioServicio + ":" + Properties.Settings.Default.claveServicio);
        //request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);

        request.Accept = "text/xml";

        return request;
    }
}
```

Sobreescribes el servicio.
Buscas el archivo Reference.cs y le cambias esta linea

```
public partial class NombreDeTuServicio : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
```

Por esta otra

```
public partial class NombreDeTuServicio : overGetRequest
```

Al hacer este cambio, lo que haces es imponer tu función en medio de la llamada genérica, o sobreescribirla.
Es decir, el servicio hereda de tu función y luego tu función hereda de SoapHttpClientProtocol, así puedes insertar código

Esta linea suele estar al inicio del servicio

EDITO:
Disculpa la demora, pero no me llego el mensaje de tu respuesta.
La cabecera Accept, puede ser que necesite como dices text/xml, text/html, text/plain y que se puede necesitar indicar el dominio, dependiendo del tipo de autenticacion, pero necesito algo mas de informacion

Por otra parte, ejecutalo paso a paso y enviame la excepcion

Comment: Mil gracias. Finalmente descubrimos un problema en el servicio web que no era responsabilidad nuestra, de ahí que la respuesta devuelta, aun estando bien la solicitud, no fuera correcta.

Answer (score 2):

puedes probar agregando una referencia de servicio, lo haces de la siguiente forma:

En el proyecto vas a `Referencias` y das `click` derecho y seleccionas
: **`Agregar referencia de servicio`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar lcik, te aparece la siguiente ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si la `Url` estuviera funcionando te aparecería algo como esto Después de dar `click` en **`Ir`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora pegas tu url del servicio y presionar **`Ir`** cuando cargue le das `Aceptar` y ya tienes la referencia a tu servicio , cuando hagas esto ya puedes llamar la referencia en tu proyecto y acceder a los métodos del servicio.

Para consumir el servicio Lo haces de la siguiente forma.

**Primero** Agregar los using

```
 using GT_PrjERP.Data.WorkManagerService;
```

**Segundo** Creas una variable del tipo del servicio:

```
private WorkManagerServicesClient objWorkManager = new WorkManagerServicesClient();
```

Ya dependiendo de los parametros que reciba cada Metodo creas variables del tipo que necesitas enviar. Ej:

```
InsertRequestDto request = new InsertRequestDto();

HeaderDto headerUserDto = new HeaderDto();

headerUserDto.Token = "lABkYtykmKanRwun5dG4tZlPHTUHeseI";
headerUserDto.User = "EmpresaUser";
request.Data = DataUser;
request.FormCode = "4";
request.Header = headerUserDto;
request.OfficeCode = "4";
request.OperationUser = "UsuarioConectado";
```

Y  por ultimo puedes acceder a los métodos del servicio con la variable así:

```
objWorkManager.Form_Insert(request);
```

El `Form_Insert` es un método de mi servicio.

Comment: La **`url`**  que das en la pregunta del servicio no esta funcionando , por los mismo no puede realizar el ejemplo completo.

Comment: No debo poner en internet claves y url del servicio. Lo siento, gracias por colaborar. Al final había un problema en el servicio, ajeno a mí, de ahí que no funcionara bien.

Answer (score 0):

Cesar, voy viendo lo que me planteas.
Lo he modificado tal y como me dices, pero me vuelve a salir el mismo error. Es como que no hiciera lo que debe (depurando veo que entra en la clase overGetRequest). He modificado la primera línea de Reference.cs poniendo
  `public partial class pedidos : overGetRequest` 
y he creado la nueva clase (aunque modificando algunas cosas referentes al usuario/clave:

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    public class overGetRequest : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
    {

      protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
      {
          ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

          HttpWebRequest request;
          request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
          //Esto esta comentado por si no necesitas autenticar
          string credentialBuffer = "usuario" + ":" + "clave";
          request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + credentialBuffer;

          request.Accept = "text/xml";

          return request;
      }
    }
```

¿Podría ser que necesite indicar el domain en la autenticación?
¿request.Accept = text/xml o debe ser igual a text/html?
Si el error fuera la clave, daría otro fallo, ¿cierto?

Comment: Si necesitas preguntar algo sobre alguna de las respuestas, lo mejor es dejarle un comentario en la respuesta. Tbn es valido que modifiques tu respuesta aclarando la actualizacion de la misma.

Comment: Es importante revises [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //¿Como les fue?, es que no lo logro tampoco.
    ApcRemoteClient apcRemote = new ApcRemoteClient();
                // Configura las credenciales del cliente
                apcRemote.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = username;
                apcRemote.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = password;
                apcRemote.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Domain   = url;
                //Uri create
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                apcRemote.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.GetCredential(uri, "Digest");

                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
                getNextFreeOntId(apcRemote);
```